# How To Keep Common CSS And JS Files For Multiple Web Projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, .net-framework-version

- All the projects are in asp.net web forms using donet framework 4.7.2.
- I have 40 projects with the same project configurations ( All are web forms and the framework is  4.7.2).
- I have created a folder named 'Assets' and kept all my CSS and JS files including MasterPage(Layout. Master).
- I would like to keep the 'Assets' folder (somewhere?) to be accessed by all the other 40 projects.
- The intent of this is to update any new changes for just one folder and the changes will take effect for all
  other projects. On top of that, I'd like to avoid creating duplicate Assets folders for all the other 40 projects.
- I would like to keep the 'Assets' folder (somewhere?) to be accessed by all the other 40 projects.
- The intent of this is to update any new changes for just one folder and the changes will take  effect for all other projects. On top of that, I'd like to avoid creating duplicate Assets folders for all the other 40 projects.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I've achieved a simlier resolution by creating my own cdn. There's a great tutorial here
https://dev.to/megajakob/how-to-build-your-own-cdn-io1.the tutorial covers many ways to achieve this but all of them cost some money.
For me the final solution was IIS static caching have a look at http://www.galcho.com/blog/post/2008/02/27/IIS7-How-to-set-cache-control-for-static-content.aspx and setting up a static website on IIS
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/creating-websites/scenario-build-a-static-website-on-iis
my final solution allowed for the functionality without using any addition cost of using a third-party provider.